# VLC tags don't show, need to edit

Tags: vlc

When accessing audio file information, no tags appear like desktop version. How am I supposed to edit tags

[Screenshot of "information" menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EulrG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not inplemented and has a low priority: https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/7072

There are many alternative tools in the play store that offer this feature.